# CentOS Comm not sorting correctly?

Tags: shell

I've been trying to use comm to find the differences between two text files. After searching, I've attempted to use many suggestions (comm, diff, whatever, but I'm using comm as an example.) but it can't isolate the one actual different line

comm -23 <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt)

a.txt:

```
asd
dsa
ere
```

b.txt:

```
asd
dsa
```

result:

```
dsa
ere
```

Comment: When I run your command `comm -23 <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt)` it outputs  `ere`

Answer (score 0):

This will isolate the one actual different line:

```
$ sort a.txt b.txt | uniq -u
ere
```